# Rails validation for presence is incorrently throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.x and I have a presence validator for the due date of an "rfq".  But this validator always throws the error even if the due date is set!

Here is the validation in question (rfq.rb):

```
validates :due, presence:{ message:" date must be set"}
```

I think it has something to do with this line in my controller for the same model:

```
if @rfq.due.present?
  @rfq.due = Date.strptime(rfq_params[:due].to_str,"%m-%d-%Y")
  @rfq.due = @rfq.due.change(hour: 15)
end
```

any help is appreciated.

EDIT: added trace (I hope, still new to this)

```
Started POST "/rfqs" for 192.168.1.29 at 2015-08-17 15:45:39 -0500
Cannot render console from 192.168.1.29! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by RfqsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BfYwpLx5jos+lZCAnefuwgIK1UCW5Lh1xo6V72v9Hlw8JPl8igQrD8Tiuhfo0vvCYIyBdMV/PDEQqImTrvhQDg==", "rfq"=>{"customer_name"=>"Matha Laswell", "customer_id"=>"8", "priority"=>"LOW", "vendor_id"=>"1", "placeholder"=>"1", "due"=>"08-18-2015", "mandatory_due_date"=>"0", "is_budgetary"=>"0", "ship_date"=>"standard", "end_user_list"=>"", "application_list"=>"", "notes"=>""}, "weeks"=>"1", "commit"=>"Create Rfq"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 4]]
Unpermitted parameter: priority
  [1m[35mCustomer Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  rollback transaction
  [1m[36mVendor Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors"[0m
  Rendered rfqs/_rfq_attachment_fields.html.slim (0.9ms)
  Rendered rfqs/_quote_fields.html.slim (0.7ms)
  [1m[35mVendor Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mFormAttribute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "form_attributes".* FROM "form_attributes" WHERE "form_attributes"."vendor_id" = ? AND (attribute = 'productline')[0m  [["vendor_id", 1]]
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mFormAttribute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "form_attributes".* FROM "form_attributes" WHERE "form_attributes"."vendor_id" = ? AND (attribute = 'discwedge')[0m  [["vendor_id", 1]]
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mFormAttribute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "form_attributes".* FROM "form_attributes" WHERE "form_attributes"."vendor_id" = ? AND (attribute = 'valvetype')[0m  [["vendor_id", 1]]
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mFormAttribute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "form_attributes".* FROM "form_attributes" WHERE "form_attributes"."vendor_id" = ? AND (attribute = 'valveends')[0m  [["vendor_id", 1]]
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mFormAttribute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "form_attributes".* FROM "form_attributes" WHERE "form_attributes"."vendor_id" = ? AND (attribute = 'valvematerial')[0m  [["vendor_id", 1]]
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mFormAttribute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "form_attributes".* FROM "form_attributes" WHERE "form_attributes"."vendor_id" = ? AND (attribute = 'valveconfig')[0m  [["vendor_id", 1]]
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mFormAttribute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "form_attributes".* FROM "form_attributes" WHERE "form_attributes"."vendor_id" = ? AND (attribute = 'class')[0m  [["vendor_id", 1]]
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mFormAttribute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "form_attributes".* FROM "form_attributes" WHERE "form_attributes"."vendor_id" = ? AND (attribute = 'operator')[0m  [["vendor_id", 1]]
  Rendered rfqs/_line_item_fields.html.slim (4.6ms)
  Rendered rfqs/_valve_fields_xanik.html.slim (19.3ms)
  Rendered rfqs/_form.html.slim (49.7ms)
  Rendered rfqs/new.html.slim within layouts/application (50.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1519ms (Views: 1496.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

EDIT: accidentally fixed it

So I changed

```
@rfq = Rfq.new(rfq_params)
@rfq.owner = current_user.first_name.titleize
if @rfq.due.present?
  @rfq.due = Date.strptime(rfq_params[:due].to_str,"%m-%d-%Y")
  @rfq.due = @rfq.due.change(hour: 15)
end
```

to

```
@rfq = Rfq.new(rfq_params)
@rfq.owner = current_user.first_name.titleize
if rfq_params[:due].present?
  @rfq.due = Date.strptime(rfq_params[:due].to_str,"%m-%d-%Y")
  @rfq.due = @rfq.due.change(hour: 15)
end
```

and now it works but I don't really understand why...

Sorry if this is obvious, I'm just new to Rails

Comment: Why don't you inspect `@rfq` at the point where the validation fires? What does `puts @rfq.due unless @rfq.valid?` give you?

Comment: @Anthony The validation just says that the date is missing when the controller lines are included. "1 error: Due date must be set"

Comment: 1.- Full stack trace, please. 2.- Why do you set it _when_ it's present?

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm still new to rails. I'm trying what @axelTetzlaff said.  I'll get the trace asap.

Comment: It works now, added the last edit. Thank you for your time, hope it wasn't too much trouble.